# Using tabulate() with numbers with decimals

Tags: r

I have a vector

```
a<- c(0.2849579, 0.2849579, 0.2849579)
```

I would like to use:

```
tabulate(a,nbins=max(a))
```

but this returns `integer(0)` as output.

Can tabulate be used for numbers with decimals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some random numbers, replicated

```
x = sample(runif(10), 1000, TRUE)
```

Find the unique (optionally, rounding to significant figures) values, then find the index of each `x` in the table of unique values and tabulate those

```
## x = signif(x, 6)
ux = sort(unique(x))
idx = match(x, ux)
n = tabulate(idx, nbins=length(ux))
```

finally, summarize the results

```
df = data.frame(x=ux, n=n)
```

Use the summary to see all counts

```
> head(df)
           x   n
1 0.02832152 108
2 0.04973473  90
3 0.19770913  96
4 0.31591234 103
5 0.59334322  97
6 0.64145901  98
```

or identify values with maximum counts

```
> df[df$n ==  max(df$n), , drop=FALSE]
           x   n
10 0.9711141 127
```

Comment: thanks, but I need to use nbins=max() because I'm trying to determine the majority number in the vector

Comment: @user1723765 I don't understand, the answer tabulates the indexes not the values. Maybe you want `ux[which.max(n)]`.

Comment: +1 very nice idea. I wonder how much floating point representation (/tolerance) will play a role in getting `unique` values... Ex: `x <- c(1.23456789123, 1.23456789124); unique(x)` it'd be nice to have an option to have just one value here.

Comment: @Arun yes, I think it would be necessary to round to desired significant figures up front; I modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `nbins` determines the number of bins in which the numbers are put. Since `max(a) = 0.2849579` there will be zero bins and therefore your result is to be expected.

Also the help page for `tabulate` (called with `?tabulate`) says:

> If the elements of ‘bin’ are numeric but not integers, they are truncated to the nearest integer.

Depending on your problem you may want to upscale your decimals first and then apply `tabulate`. Or you might want to use `hist` or something like that instead.