# How to find the number of identical elements in two vectors?

Tags: r

I have two vectors:

```
 a <- letters[1:5]
 b <- c('a','k','w','p','b','b')
```

Now I want to count how many times each letter in vector `a` shows up in `b`. I want to get:

```
 # 1  2  0  0  0
```

What should I do?

Comment: Seems like homework to me

Comment: what? What do you mean?

Answer (score 5):

`tabulate` works on integer vectors and is fast; match your letters to the universe of possible letters, then tabulate the index; use `length(a)` to ensure that there is one count for each possible value.

```
> tabulate(match(b, a), length(a))
 [1] 1 2 0 0 0
```

This is faster than the 'obvious' table() solution

```
library(microbenchmark)
f0 = function() table(factor(b,levels=a))
f1 = function() tabulate(match(b, a), length(a))
```

and then

```
> microbenchmark(f0(), f1())
Unit: microseconds
 expr     min       lq  median       uq     max neval
 f0() 566.824 576.2985 582.950 594.4200 798.275   100
 f1()  56.816  60.0180  63.305  65.4185 120.441   100
```

but also more general, e.g., [matching numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746475/using-tabulate-with-numbers-with-decimals/20747297#20747297) without coercing to a string representation.

Answer (score 4):

Make `b` into a factor with the levels specified by `a`.  Values that are not in `a` will turn into `<NA>`.  When you tabulate, they will be discarded (unless you specify `useNA="ifany"`).

```
table(factor(b,levels=a))

a b c d e 
1 2 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>sapply(a, function(x) sum(x==b))

a b c d e 
1 2 0 0 0
```

Alternative solution. The anonymouse function can be modified to implement fuzzy name matching with a package such as `stringdist`